# Devise reset password email points to the wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I included `devise_token_auth` to login from a webapp hosted elsewhere. But I'd like also to be able to sign in directly into my rails app.

My routes.rb looks like this:

```
#...
devise_for :users

namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
  #...
```

To reset the password the webapp sends a `POST` to `/api/auth/password`. With the configuration above, the link in the email to reset the password uses the wrong controller (the one on `users/password`). The redirect_url doesn't get applied and the user sees the login form of the rails app, not the webapp:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?redirect_url=http://localhost:8080/reset_password&reset_password_token=...
```

If I comment the line `devise_for :users` the email link is correct, using `api/auth/password/edit`:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/password/edit?redirect_url=http://localhost:8080/reset_password&reset_password_token=...
```

But of course, by commenting `devise_for :users` I can't login using just the rails app (on `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise, on its mailer template to reset the password (`reset_password_instructions.html.erb`) calls onto the model to get the url:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>
```

Although the controller that initially handled the client intent to reset the password was `DeviseTokenAuth::PasswordsController`, the function `edit_password_url` on `User` resolves to a path to be handled by `Devise::PasswordsController` (`users/password/edit` vs `api/auth/password/edit`).

The **solution** in this case was to use a different model:

*routes.rb*

```
#...
devise_for :users

namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'Api::User', at: 'auth'
  #...
```

*api/user.rb*

```
class Api::User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable,
     :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
   #...
end
```